# Help Solving a Recurrence Relation with an Inverse Term

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recurrence-relations

I am having a hard time generating a characteristic polynomial for a recurrence relation I thought of the other day, $a_n = a_{n-1} + \frac1{a_{n-1}}$.

I am pretty familiar solving basic recurrence relations such as $F_n = F_{n-2} + F_{n-1}$ being $x^2 = x + 1$, but this solution seems to escape me.

I recognize the fact that this will probably look something akin to a logarithm because we are constantly adding smaller and smaller $1/x$, but beyond that I am lost.

I do not know how to approach this, and my discrete math is a bit rusty.. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Not every recurrence has a (closed-form) solution. $a_n=(1/2)(a_{n-1}+a_{n-1}^{-1})$ approaches 1. $a_n=(1/2)(a_{n-1}-a_{n-1}^{-1})$ is chaotic.

Comment: See http://oeis.org/A073833 and http://oeis.org/A073834 for what happens when $a_0=1$.

Comment: Very interesting Gerry! Thank you for the guidance.